# Cannot connect to Windows Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

Are there any settings concerning the connection to the Windows Store?

I find I cannot connect to it after refreshing my computer. I got the following message for two days. I don't think Windows Store is down, so there must be something wrong.

My internet connection is working fine. I can also use the Game store, Bing and anything else, but just can not connect to the Windows Store.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a dns issue.  Have you contacted your ISP and reported the problem?

Comment: No, I don't know my ISP.

Comment: Does your internet work? what country are you in?

Comment: Yes, my internet works, I am in China.

Comment: In China. Is it possible that you are blocked from the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refresh my computer again, it works now, don't know the reason, I recommand users to do a pure install of windows 8, upgrade from Windows 7 may cause problems, I have refreshed my computer twice.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a proxy server or an application between you and the Microsoft store that is preventing you from connecting.

For example, to test this I started [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to see if I could determine what traffic the Microsoft Store was creating. However, when I did that I got the same error message as you. When I closed fiddler then the store worked fine.

I would check the list of processes you have running using process explorer to see if there is anything running that you don't recognize since you might have a virus or some other program that is acting as a proxy or pass-though service.